# method of allocating documents to pre-defined classifications

Tags: classification, lda

I'm looking for a method of allocating documents (30K and growing) to a set of some 200 categories.

The categories will be user defined and will grow over time.

As my data is unlabelled my thought process is to try an build a system that aids in the manual classification by providing a rough first pass classifier. User can then quickly go through the classified documents and accept/reject the classifications.

Once we have a sufficient large set of classified documents then I'm hoping to use some AI system to automatically classify the remaining documents and new ones as they are published.

I've had a play with LDA but as I understand it, LDA essentially chooses the topics which don't necessarily map to the categories that I want to define.

I've have also built a rule engine that allows me to manually define common key words to map each document to a category but this is still a fairly manual process as I need to define keywords for each of the categories.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-output classification for text input could be done thanks to [Random Forest Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

First, you need to vectorize your text to make your data multidimensional and allow the Classifier to segregate the data easily.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Extract features with a word frequency (for example)
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(texts)
```

Then, you can apply the Random Forest Classifier from sklearn that would automatically classify the vectorized data easily.

```
#Train/test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, labels, test_size=0.2)

# Training
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, max_depth=15)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

# Model accuracy
accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

X_test would be the text input and y_pred the multi-output classification result.

Alternatively, you can use [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) instead of CountVectorizer.

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know to provide additional information or other solutions.

Comment: I don't understand how this allocates documents to my predefined categories?

Comment: Could you add a simple example with some input/outputs so that I could answer more accurately?

Comment: The plan is to categorize all of the readmes on pub.dev. eg. https://pub.dev/packages/chopper.  An example category would be communications.http.client. I will pre-define the set of categories and want each readme allocated to one.